# I have a problem removing; of a column with the substring in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The problem is that I have a column called email and I have to remove the last one; and I don't know how to do it. I have tried with the substring and len but I don't get any help

```
update e
email = case
          when email like '%;' then substring(email, -1, len(email))
from example
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Sample data and desired results also help.

Comment: Do you by any chance have multiple emails in a single field separated by `;`? Look up `STRING_SPLIT`, there are hundreds of examples online

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```
update e
    set email = substring(email, 1, len(email) - 1)
    where email like '%;';
```

This uses the functions from your code, so I assume your database supports them.

Note that emails don't normally have semicolons in them *anywhere*, so I might be inclined to write:

```
update e
    set email = replace(email, ';', '')
    where email like '%;%';
```

Comment: This field was later used to send emails so they have one; but what happens is that when I delete a field I keep it; in the end and I don't know how to remove that character

Comment: @Saclor . . . Your fundamental problem is that you have a bad data model.  You should not be storing multiple values in a single, string column.

Comment: You are right but they have asked me in class